# How Can I Take Many Chars and Put Them Into One String

Tags: c++, string, char

I suppose I just never learned this. I have never done this before. I have seen the use of `strcat(S1, S2)`, but that isn't applicable here, is it?

Can I do something like

```
string all_possible_strings[10]; 
char jumbled_chars[] = "ABCDEFG";
all_possible_strings[1] = jumbled_chars[0] << jumbled_chars[1] 
                              << jumbled_chars[2] << jumbled_chars[3] 
                              << jumbled_chars[4];
```

What I'm trying to do is make a program that can unscramble a word into all of its possible permutations.

Comment: Where are the chars to begin with?  If they're already in an array, then all you'd have to do is append a null character (\0), I think.

Comment: Your question implies that you don't understand how strings in C++ work. Maybe you should start at a more basic, general, level? If you have a specific scenario you need help with, provide the details.

Comment: all_possible_strings[counter] = jumbled_chars[0] << jumbled_chars[1] << jumbled_chars[2] << jumbled_chars[3] << jumbled_chars[4];

Comment: Although I know I don't use the << stream operator

Comment: `str += c;` is how you append a char to a string, or use the `append` function.

Comment: Don't expand your question in the comments like that. Edit instead. I've done this one for you.

Comment: @anthony-arnold: `std::string str("whatever"); str+=c;` is how you expand a *standard string*, but fails horribly if he is using c-string.

Comment: What are the types of `all_possible_strings` and `jumbled_chars`?

Comment: string all_possible_strings[]

Comment: Yes, but when the tags say `c++` and `string`, I assume an `std::string` until further notice. Question is ambiguous at best right now.

Comment: whenever I use += and cout the strings, it comes out with gibberish ascii values

Comment: Can you update the question with what you're trying?

Comment: @anthony-arnold I assumed you did, but you should be explicit when addressing a user who may be struggling with the basics.

Answer (score 7):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        string theString = "";
        char a = 'a';
        char b = 'b';
        const char* c = "cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

        theString += a;
        theString += b;
        theString += c;

        cout << theString;
        return 0;
}
```

That prints out the entire alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `append` function or the `operator+=` overload of `std::string`. You should read up on the [STL documentation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/basic_string.html).

If `jumbled_chars` is already in the order you want it, then you could just construct the string like

```
all_possible_strings[counter] = std::string(jumbled_chars, 5);
```

**Update:**

Ok, here's a few suggestions. Instead of storing your strings in an array, use `std::vector` instead.

```
std::vector<std::string> possible_strings;
std::string jumbled_chars; //This could be a char[] or char* or whatever
```

I'll leave figuring our exactly how to get all permutations of a string as an exercise for the reader. But say you want to get `jumbled_chars` in the order of `w`, `x`, `y`, `z`, where `w-z` are indices of `jumbled_chars`:

```
std::string str = "";
str += jumbled_chars[w];
str += jumbled_chars[x];
str += jumbled_chars[y];
str += jumbled_chars[z];

possible_strings.push_back(str);
```

Comment: cppreference.com is easier to read. The SGI STL docs are almost as verbose as the ISO spec itself.